# extend Comparable generic in a final class

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I try to extend Comparable<> in my final class but I have no clue why it throughs this error.

```
public final class Identifier extends Comparable<Identifier> {

...

}
```

ERROR: The type Comparable cannot be the superclass of Identifier; a superclass must be a class

But isnt Comparable a class? I don't get it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: No; that's an interface.

Comment: This happens because `Comparable<T>` is an interface. You need to use `implements` instead of `extends`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's an interface. You implement interfaces, you don't extend them.  You need

```
public final class Identifier implements Comparable<Identifier> {
  ...
}
```